# How to compare two functions at infinity for asymptotic analysis?

Tags: definition, analytic-geometry

On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote) wikipedia page its mentioned that "asymptote of a curve is a line such that the distance between the curve and the line approaches zero as one or both of the x or y coordinates tends to infinity"

But on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) page it has compared $n^2+3n$ and $n^2$ and claimed them to be asymptotically equivalent.

I get it that their ratio approaches one as $x \to \infty$ which means they are equal.

But their difference is $3n$ which is also approaching $\infty$. How can two functions with infinite difference be equal? Also it goes against the first links definition that the distance should be approaching zero, which is not the case here as its approaching $\infty$

The basic problem which I am facing is (according to me) : Are $1000000100000$ and $1000000000000$ nearly equal? Their ratio is pretty close to one but there difference is 100000, which is quite big I think.

Comment: Big is a relative word. Their difference is small compared to their size

Comment: $1000000100000= 1000000000000\left( 1+0.0000001\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two distinct notions at play here. For a given function $f$, the first notion is [*an asymptote*](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Asymptote), a line $l$ whose distance $|l(x)-f(x)|$ from $f$ tends to $0$ as $x\to\infty$, while the second notion is [*asymptotic equivalence*/*equality*](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Asymptotic_equality), a relation satisfied by a function $g$ whose quotient $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$ with $f$ tends to $1$ as $x\to\infty$. The first represents a line, specifically, that $f$ gets near to, in the ordinary, additive sense of "near" as a small absolute difference. But the latter represents a function that grows or vanishes at a similar rate to $f$, in a multiplicative sense. This might immediately ring alarm bells that they aren't the same thing, since a line has only one rate of growth: linear!

Now, either difference near $0$ or a quotient near $1$ can represent some sense of nearness. But one does not necessarily imply the other. We can refer to these two additive and multiplicative types of nearness as *absolute* and *relative*, respectively. For example, considering only numbers, $0.001$ and $0.000\,001$ are both tiny and hence near one another in an absolute sense, but they are far in a *relative* sense since one is $1000$ times the other. And vice versa, $100\,000\,000$ and $100\,010\,000$ may be *absolutely* far as they have a difference of $10\,000$, but as they are huge numbers on the same order (i.e., number of digits), they are relatively close!

Translating this idea back to functions, as $x\to\infty$, both $1/x$ and $1/x^2$ tend to $0$ but at different rates. Hence, they tend nearer to one another absolutely but not relatively (i.e., they are not asymptotic). On the other hand, $x$ and $x+1$ maintain a constant difference that is dwarfed by their size. Hence, they tend nearer to one another relatively (i.e., they are asymptotic) but not absolutely.

So, an "asymptote (line) of $f$" may not actually be "asymptotic to $f$". It should generally be obvious from context what is meant, but be careful about your terminology.

Comment: I agree with everything you're saying except that every source I can recall, including the one you linked in this very post, defines an asymptote (line) to be asymptotic in the common relative sense and not near in the absolute sense.

Comment: Thanks sir/mam. Do these 2 types of nearness come from the fact that there exists one identity each for multiplication and addition on real numbers? So if we have some algebraic structure with (say) 3 identities for 3 different operations, then that structure will have 3 types of nearness?